# Django form used multiple times in single HTML and avoid duplicate id

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-forms, django-templates

> Python 3.6.3, Django 1.11.8, Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official
>   Build) (64-bit)

I have a create project form.
Which is added multiple modals in html code.

I used prefix attribute in form class, with this can avoid duplicate ID from other forms same name fields.

But how to deal with same name multiple ID created by one form used multiple time in single html ?

form.py

```
class CreateProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'create_project'
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_type', 'description']
        widgets = {'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'description'})}
```

My Form is working fine. but I am keep getting this error in Chrome Developer console:

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #id_create_project-description:  <input type=​"text" name=​"create_project-description" placeholder=​"description" maxlength=​"200" id=​"id_create_project-description">​ <input type=​"text" name=​"create_project-description" placeholder=​"description" maxlength=​"200" id=​"id_create_project-description">​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #id_create_project-project_name: <input type=​"text" name=​"create_project-project_name" maxlength=​"50" required id=​"id_create_project-project_name">​ <input type=​"text" name=​"create_project-project_name" maxlength=​"50" required id=​"id_create_project-project_name">​
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #id_create_project-project_type: <select name=​"create_project-project_type" required id=​"id_create_project-project_type">​…​</select>​ <select name=​"create_project-project_type" required id=​"id_create_project-project_type">​…​</select>​
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Create separate form instances in your view, each with a different [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix):

   ```
   f1 = CreateProjectForm(prefix='f1')
   f2 = CreateProjectForm(prefix='f2')
   ```

   And then render each form separately - the prefix will ensure they have unique IDs.
2. If for some reason you want to use the same form class, or don't know how many instances you will be rendering, then you can [render the form manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and either omit the IDs or use some outer logic to determine a prefix for the IDs.