# Django (HTML) - Clickable label in template (not working)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm working on a Django project where I would like using some customized checkbox forms when this issue shown up. *Both code chunks are exactly the same*, but using different forms. The issue comes when the first's sample label is clickable (so I can hide the radio button), but the second one is not working as expected, the user must click on the radio button, if I hide it the whole label becomes useless.

**WORKING PROPERLY**:

```
<form action="" class="form-group" method="POST">
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset >
                    
                    {% for radio in form_emp.producto %}
                    <li style="list-style-type:none">
                        <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}
                            <label class="label" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">   
                                {{ radio.choice_label }}
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </fieldset>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{form_emp.cantidad.label}}
            {{form_emp.cantidad}}
            {{form_emp.observaciones.label}}
            {{form_emp.observaciones}}
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Agregar" />
</div>
```

**NOT WORKING PROPERLY**:

```
<form action="" class="form-group" method="POST">
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset > 
                    {% for radio in form_pizzas.producto %}
                    <li style="list-style-type:none">
                        <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}
                            <label class="label" for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">   
                                {{ radio.choice_label }}
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </fieldset>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{form_pizzas.cantidad.label}}
            {{form_pizzas.cantidad}}
            {{form_pizzas.observaciones.label}}
            {{form_pizzas.observaciones}}
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Agregar" />
</div>
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
    #WORKING FORM         
class CartEmpanadasForm(ModelForm):
    lista_prod=Producto.objects.filter(categoria=1)
    producto=forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=lista_prod)

    class Meta:
        model=Cart
        fields=["producto","cantidad","observaciones"]

#NOT WORKING FORM
class CartPizzasForm(ModelForm):
    #LISTA DE PRODUCTOS, FILTRO POR CATEGORÍA
    lista_prod=Producto.objects.filter(categoria=2)
    #MOSTRAR LOS ELEMENTOS COMO UN CHOICEFIELD
    producto=forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=lista_prod)

    class Meta:
        model=Cart
        fields=["producto","cantidad","observaciones"]
```

**CSS File**

```
label{
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #1881f9;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(178, 201, 243);
    transition: 5ms;}


input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 6px solid #f95818;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgb(178, 201, 243);}
```

I hope you guys could help me figure out what is going on there! Thank you so much in advance! Have a nice week!

Comment: Can you show the two differents `foms.py`  file ?

Comment: Hi! The question was updated! Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was showing more than one form in the same view, as default the form's tag-id are "id_columnname_n", so the multiple forms weren't allowing to identify the tags properly. The label id was repeated.
I solved introducing customized ids in the forms.py file and setting manually every label-tag in the template.

FORMS.py

```
class CartEmpanadasForm(ModelForm):
#LISTA DE PRODUCTOS, FILTRO POR CATEGORÍA
lista_prod=Producto.objects.filter(categoria=1)
#MOSTRAR LOS ELEMENTOS COMO UN CHOICEFIELD
producto=forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'empanada','id':'empanada'}), queryset=lista_prod)

class Meta:
    model=Cart
    fields=["producto","cantidad","observaciones"]
```

VIEW.html

```
<fieldset >
{% for radio in form_emp.producto %}
<li style="list-style-type:none">
    <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}
        <label class="label" for="empanada_{{forloop.counter0}}">   
            {{ radio.choice_label }}
        </label>
    </span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: See [Django form used multiple times in single HTML and avoid duplicate id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842856/django-form-used-multiple-times-in-single-html-and-avoid-duplicate-id)